# How to add a property to represent a sample name that may not be changed once initialized?

Tags: c#, class, properties, immutability

I am trying to make a property in my class. What would I need to do where once the property is initialized, it cannot be changed?

These are the actual instructions:

> Create a class in the existing namespace, either in an existing code
>   file or in a new file, to represent the amount in pounds of dirt
>   sample. In this class (a) do not create constructors. (b) inherit the
>   sand class (to make use of the sand property). **(c) add a property to
>   represent the sample name. This property may not be changed once
>   initialized.** (d) add a property to represent and process assignments
>   the quantity of clay, with a minimum value of 0. (e) add methods to
>   return the weight of the sample, the percentage of sand in the sample
>   and the percentage of clay in the sample.

I am on part (c). I have tried to exclude setters. Then, I've tried to use readonly, but it cannot work because my class cannot have constructors.

```
public class AmountSand //parent class
    {
    public class AmountSand {
 private double quantity;
 public double Sand {

  get {
   return quantity;
  }
  set {
   if (value >= 0) quantity = value;
  }
 }
}

public class AmountDirt: AmountSand { //part (b): inherited the parent class, AmountSand
  private string name = null;
  private double clay;

  public string Name { //here is where the specific property starts
   get {
    return name;
   }
   set {
    if (name == null)
     name = value;
   }
  } //ends

  public double Clay {
   get {
    return clay;
   }
   set {
    if (value >= 0) clay = value;
   }
  }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? How do you mean cannot have ctor, it must have ctor...maybe is is not visible but must be there or the class is static? You mean it has parameterless ctor?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the full instructions and code for clarification. It is just a homework requirement. Not really sure about parameterless constructor. Is that default? I have just started this language.

Comment: if you do not define any ctor you have public parameterless ctor by default. Actually your code works but it is vague and uncommon. If you want to follow OOP best practices once after construct the object you should have a consistent well-formed object which is not the case in your example...

Comment: Ah I see, so it checks if name is null. If so, it assigns it the first round value (initialized). Then if it is trying to overwrite it, it will check again and see it is not null, so it disregards it?? Would I need to include an else statement?

Comment: If the setter guards against re-setting a value then there is no need for "readonly"

Comment: *Not really sure about parameterless constructor. Is that default?*.  If you write a parameterless constructor it overrides the default constructor. Parameters or not, any constructor you supply overrides the default constructor. As far as I know a default constructor with parameters is a non-concept.

Comment: *...cannot be changed after initialization* Precisely speaking,  Object field Initialization happens before the constructor is called - that is `private string name = null;` is done before the default constructor (or one you wrote) is executed. Passing a constructor parameter or using a property setter both happen after initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on from where you would like it to be initialized.

EDIT: sorry, i didn't read that your class could have ctors, but i'll keep this in for completeness.  It seems kinda weird that your class can't have ctors.  May I ask why?

From the ctor:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Name = "Muhammed";
    }

    public MyClass(string newName)
    {
        Name = newName;
    }

    public string Name{get;}
}
```

If you'd like it to be initialized from outside the class, your code is not too far off.  You could even remove the backing property.  I'd use

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
```

rather than comparing to null.

if you'd like it to be set from a method inside your class:

```
public string Name{get; private set;}
```

Comment: take a look at `IsNullOrWhitespace` in lieu of `IsNullOrEmpty`.  It covers more "whitespace" cases.

Comment: As I understand, making the set private will fulfill the requirement of the property not being able to change after initializing?

Comment: @radarbob Sure, good point, could use that to be more restrictive...unless '\n' etc are allowed.

Comment: @Aashna Well, not specifically.  It will allow you to control how and when it's set because the setter is only accessible from inside your class.  If you tell us how this will be used, we can help further.  Check out [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are already immutable by nature, so you need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

However, if you simply don't want anything else to be able to set the value other than the class itself, then you can make the set accessor private.